# What is missing in this gravitational time dilation derivation?

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration, time-dilation, gravitational-redshift

I am confused about one derivation of the gravitational time dilation.

Consider a one dimensional time-independent gravitational field. Two clocks are at rest with respect to the gravitational field and located at positions $h_1$ and $h_2$ respectively. Release a third clock with an initial speed $v_1$ at $h_1$ free falling toward $h_2$ and will pass by Clock 2 at $h_2$ with speed $v_2$. Clock $3$ is an inertial frame so we observe the other two clocks in this frame. As it passes by each clock, it will observe a time dilation. We have
$$\gamma_1dt_1 = dt_3=\gamma_2dt_2 \tag1$$
where $\gamma_i$ is the Lorentz factor and $t_i$ the time in frame $i$.

It seems this dilation derivation depends on the initial speed $v_1$ which is contrary to the usual formula such as the one in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Definition)
$$T_d(h) = \exp\left[\frac{1}{c^2}\int_0^h g(h') dh'\right] \tag2$$
where $T_d(h)$ is the ''total'' time dilation at a distant position $h$, $g(h)$ is the dependence of g-force on "height" $h$, $c$ is the speed of light, and the initial speed $v_1$ makes no appearance.

What is wrong with Equation $(1)$? I know the more mathematically clean, clear and simple derivation of the gravitational time dilation from metric (such as the one provided by @Dale). The derivation above is quite persuasive as it resorts apparently to the equivalence principle by looking at the locally inertial frame of the free falling clock 3. My concern here is what exactly goes wrong in this line of reasoning.

Comment: Without more details on the derivation, I suspect that it assumes that $v \ll c$ throughoutout and then uses the first-year kinematic equation $v_2^2 - v_1^2 = 2g(h_1 - h_2)$ for a freely falling object.  If that's the case, then the precise initial velocity doesn't matter.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: This derivation comes from *Hans C. Ohanian*, Gravitation and Spacetime, 3rd Edition, Section 3.5, p.119-120. He says under Equation (3.120) which is exactly the equation in my question that "this result is exact". Do you have a copy of the book?

Comment: I don't have a copy of it, unfortunately.  That said, my comment was more trying to address the question of "how is the gravitational redshift derived from this equation" rather than "where does this equation come from".  My point was that the initial velocity $v_1$ and the final velocity $v_2$ are related in such a way that their particular values don't matter in the final formula.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: "Initial velocity $_1$ and the final velocity $_2$ are related in such a way that their particular values don't matter in the final formula." It seems they do matter in the exact formulation --- I understand fully they approximately are under the low speed assumption. However, it is the exact formulation I care about. On that note, do you see any error in the argument itself?

Comment: I think the equation is correct as it stands, with the definitions as given above.  But without more information about how this equation is subsequently used in the derivation of the gravitational redshift equation, I can't speak to the accuracy or the limitations of the subsequent derivation.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: (1) I added the formula from Wikipedia as Equation $(2)$ which has no $v_1$ in it. How is that formula derived? (2) Would you read the answer from Dale and the conversation beneath the answer? What is your opinion regarding it?

Comment: I rolled back yesterday’s edits. You asked yesterday’s edits as a new question ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797640/derive-this-gravitational-time-dilation-formula ), which is a better approach rather than substantially editing a question that has already received answers.

Comment: @Hans I have flagged the moderators here. As I informed you previously, it is against the rules to revise a question which has received answers in a manner that invalidates the answers already received. You did well to post it as a new question. Let’s have the moderators decide about this one rather than us doing a bunch of contradictory rollbacks

Comment: @Dale: What are you trying to accomplish here? I see some contradictory actions here. You asked me below your answer which formula in the Wikipedia was. Now you tried to remove what you asked for after I gave it to you. Your answer never answered my very question which is where and why the approach of Equation $(1)$ is wrong. Could you please explain? I detect some unwarranted haughtiness here.

Comment: @Hans I did not ask you which formula it was in. I told you that I could not answer that part of your question because it was too vague, and I also told you that I was done. I have no intention of continuing to answer follow ups here. I have told you why the approach in equation 1 is wrong.  That is the whole second paragraph of my answer. What you detect is not haughtiness but irritation. I provided a good answer, you revised the question, I told you that was inappropriate but still answered your revised question, you have hounded me with follow up questions and further revisions. I am done

Comment: @Dale: You said the following. "I read it but it is too vague to answer. There are several formulas on that page without a v in it. So I don’t know which you are asking about." My edit to the question was precisely to provide the formula that you could not find on the Wikipedia page. Yes, you said "I am done." Then why did you edit my question after that? Are you not contradicting yourself? Also, as I said you never answered my question which is precisely **why** the Equation (1) approach is wrong.

Comment: I undid your edits because they violate the site rules. It is against the rules to edit a question which has received answers in a manner which invalidates those answers. And I did answer your question on equation 1. That is the entire second paragraph of my answer. I am stepping back. Let the moderators do as they will. I want nothing more to do with this question. I gave a good answer both to the original and to the first edit. Now it is just a waste of time

Comment: @Dale: 1) As I have stated, my edit simply provided the formula you yourself asked  for. It has nothing to do with validating or invalidating your answer.  2) Your answer never answer the question why and whether Equation (1) is wrong. If it was a waste of time, why did you come back to twiddle with my question after declaring you were "done"?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Do you care to take a look at this related question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797640/17354

Answer (score 1):

In the inertial frame there is no gravitational potential and therefore no gravitational time dilation. All time dilation in that frame is kinematic and will therefore depend on the velocity.

This is not a suitable method to derive the time dilation in the gravitational frame. It goes wrong by attempting to determine time dilation in the gravitational field through an inertial frame. That is not the equivalence principle. The equivalence principle asserts the local equivalence of a gravitational field and an accelerating frame, not an inertial frame.

If you wish to determine the time dilation in any frame the easiest approach is to start from the metric. Since you haven’t specified any, a good starting point is the weak field gravitational metric $$ds^2=-c^2 d\tau^2 = -\left( 1+\frac{2U}{c^2}\right)c^2 dt^2 + \left( 1-\frac{2U}{c^2} \right)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$$ where $U$ is the Newtonian gravitational potential. Then the time dilation is given by $$\frac{1}{\gamma}=\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\sqrt{1+\frac{2U}{c^2}-\left( 1-\frac{2U}{c^2}\right)\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$So we see that velocity is part of the time dilation in the gravitational frame also. The gravitational portion of the total time dilation is obtained by setting $v=0$ to obtain $$\frac{1}{\gamma_{grav}}=\frac{1}{\gamma}\bigg |_{v=0}=\sqrt{1+\frac{2U}{c^2}}$$

To use the equivalence principle in this scenario, we would examine the equivalent accelerating reference frame in flat spacetime instead of in the weak field gravitational metric, which is curved spacetime. Specifically, let's use the Rindler metric in Kottler Moeller coordinates: $$ds^2=-\left( 1+\frac{g X}{c^2}\right)^2 c^2 dT^2+ dX^2+dY^2 + dZ^2$$Deriving the time dilation in the equivalent accelerating frame as above we get $$\frac{1}{\gamma}= \sqrt{1+\frac{2gX}{c^2}+\frac{g^2 X^2}{c^4}-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$ and the pseudo-gravitational portion of the time dilation is $$\frac{1}{\gamma_{pseudo}}=\frac{1}{\gamma} \bigg|_{v=0}= \sqrt{1+\frac{2gX}{c^2}+\frac{g^2 X^2}{c^4}}$$

By the equivalence principle we expect these two expressions to be equal to first order in the coordinates. Indeed, with the substitution $U=gX$ and expanding to first order in $X$ we obtain $$\gamma_{grav}=1-\frac{gX}{c^2} + O(X^2)=\gamma_{pseudo}$$ or they can be made exactly equal with the substitution $U=gX + g^2 X^2/(2c^2)$ which is again equivalent to first order in $X$.

Comment: The rest frame of clock 3 is a local inertial frame. There is no gravity in that frame. Your speed $v$ differs from mine. Your $v$ is the speed of clock 1 or 2 relative to the rest frame of the gravitational field and should be $0$ in my setting, whilst my $v_i$ is the speed of clock $i$ relative to the free falling clock 3. The question is where my argument goes wrong.

Comment: @Hans yes, the $v$ in my expression is the velocity of any clock in the non-inertial frame. So for the clocks at rest indeed $v=0$, but the inertial clock will have non-zero $v$ except at one event. As I mentioned in the second paragraph, this is not a suitable approach to derive time dilation. So in my opinion your argument goes wrong at the very beginning. To me, looking at the inertial frame is not a valid way to get gravitational time dilation in the non-inertial frame. Particularly given how easy it is to derive time dilation directly from the metric.

Comment: I just revised my question in light of your answer to emphasize that the intention of my question is to pinpoint precisely the error in the provided derivation. I already suspected from the beginning, as clearly stated in my question, that this line of reasoning is wrong, which you concur by stating "this is not a suitable method to derive...". That seems to be a foregone conclusion. The question is **why** and at precisely which point the argument goes awry, given that it seems plausible/seductive to invoke the equivalence principle by looking at the inertial frame.

Comment: @Hans it is against the rules to revise a question after it has received answers in a way which invalidates the answers already received. I have updated my answer to state that the proposed method does not use the equivalence principle and that it goes wrong in its basic approach. Tomorrow I will add a section on how to correctly use the equivalence principle in this context, but I cannot do it now

Comment: I appreciate your update. My original question asks for the error in the free falling clock argument. We both agree the method is wrong. But I am asking why it is and what exactly is wrong. You previous did not answer that question explicitly. My revision does not change but only emphasizes what the original question is asking for. So it is not against the rule. I eagerly await your detailed elaboration and answer tomorrow. Thank you, Dale!

Comment: @Hans I have updated the answer. Hopefully it makes it clear how to apply the equivalence principle to this scenario

Comment: You missed a square in the $dt$ factor of the Kottler-Moeller coordinates. So you do not need to make any approximation when $v=0$. In any case, the time dilation in both metrics depends on $v$. So my question remains as to why the formula on the linked Wikipedia page is $v$ independent? Doe the integral cancel $v$?

Comment: @Hans I have corrected the typo. The rest of the math is correct, including the approximation which is necessary. I did the calculations with the square, and just missed it while transcribing to LaTeX. The approximation is there because the weak field metric has curvature while the Rindler metric does not.

Comment: OK. That is minor. The important point is this answer still does not answer my question concerning $v$. Can you read the second part of my last comment?

Comment: I read it but it is too vague to answer. There are several formulas on that page without a v in it. So I don’t know which you are asking about. I explained why your approach is fundamentally wrong. In general, total time dilation contains v. Gravitational time dilation is the part of the total time dilation that remains when v=0. At this point I am done. Good luck with your studies

Comment: I put the specific time dilation integral in my question above as Equation $(2)$. My question is how one reconciles the fact that that integral has no $v$ appearance whereas both Equation $(1)$ in my question and your formulae from metrics have $v$ explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Below "releasing" means dropping without throwing. And "gravitational time dilation" means gravitational time dilation according to an observer when the observer is not falling.

Releasing clock3 above $h1$ causes clock3 to have initial speed at $h1$. This initial speed at $h1$ causes initial time dilation at $h1$. (Or do I need to say that according to clock3 clock at $h1$ is time dilated?)

The observer released above $h1$ with the clock3 observes ticking rate difference between clock3 and the clock at $h1$ to be same as the gravitational time dilation between release point and $h1$.

Also said observer observes ticking rate difference between clock3 and clock at $h2$ to be same as the gravitational time dilation difference between the release point and $h2$.

Also said observer observes that there is a ticking rate difference between clock at $h1$ and clock at $h2$, it's the same as the gravitational time dilation difference between $h1$ and $h2$. (Observer wrote down the ticking rates when he passed the clocks)

I do not understand how this would be a **derivation** of gravitational time dilation. But luckily the question was about that initial speed, the effect of which I have hopefully explained.