# Derive this gravitational time-dilation formula

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation, gravitational-redshift

How is the following gravitational time dilation formula from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Definition) derived?
$$T_d(h) = \exp\left[\frac{1}{c^2}\int_0^h g(h') dh'\right]$$
where $T_d(h)$ is the ''total'' time dilation at a distant position $h$, $g(h)$ is the dependence of g-force on "height" $h$, $c$ is the speed of light.